# Постановка action creators в очередь

Tags: reactjs, redux

Допустим, есть приложение на react, с подключенной к нему с аутентификацией на firebase. При запуске приложения происходит action SIGN_IN_REQUEST, и результирующие SIGN_IN_SUCCESS или SIGN_IN_FAIL.
Так же есть и другие action's, которые обращаются к базе по componentDidMount, и которые подразумевают уже случившийся SIGN_IN_SUCCESS/FAIL. Проблема в том, что происходит экшн еще до ответа auth api, соответственно данных юзера еще нет.
В связи с этим вопрос, как можно дождаться выполнения SIGN_IN_SUCCESS/FAIL и уже после этого диспатчить другие actions, не подключая к каждому компоненту auth reducer, чтобы апдейтить компонент с данными об авторизации?

Comment: добавить лоадер?

Comment: и что значит "экшны, которые обращаются к базе".. экшны собственно через диспач отправляют сообщения в редьюсеры, но точно не обращаются к базе..